# Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

here is a very small piece of code.
I tested and worked for office 03, 07, 10 versions without a problem.
but on one machine running Win7 and Office 2007 fails always on this line:

```
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.xls")
```

> Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed

what is the possible solution?
P.S file is not damaged.

```
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim rRng As Excel.Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.xls")
Set oWS = oExcel.Worksheets(2)
Set rRng = oWS.Range("C01:C500")
oExcel.Visible = False
```

Comment: it should fail on `Set oWS = oExcel.Worksheets(2)` , since it needs to be `Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(2)`. what happens if you try `Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook` ?

Comment: Well, I get problem before that line, when I try to load workbook.

Comment: thank you, I will try Dim oWB as Excel.Workbook  since it is remote computer I have no access now, but I will post result later.

Comment: I'm guessing this is running in Word ?  It's not completely clear in the question...

Comment: Does the problem PC have "hide extenstions for know file types" turned on, and is the filename really "myFile.xls.xls"  ?  Just a guess...   What is the result of `Dir("C:\myFile.xls")` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it is running in Word, sorry, I forgot to mention in question. I remember it had no extension on excel files, maybe could that be really reason?

Comment: ok, I just tested without extensions on my PC and it still works here in both cases.

Comment: I tested also on wrong file/directory names and then another error was come, so I am sure file name and path are ok.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone.

I found the solution, Foxit reader add-in in word was causing the trouble.
once removed everything worked.